# HighChart using Javascript Cordova

Tags: cordova, highcharts

I am trying to fixed height of chart. I mean, height of chart is changing dependent on resolution and not suitable view for all android devices. What should I do for height is same in all devices? Here is my code:

chart.height = window.innerHeight;

Comment: Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), follow the guides and try to elaborate on what you try to achieve. For changing chart's size use [chart.setSize()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.setSize)

Comment: @ morganfree  I can change the width or height of chart.But the problem is how can be suitable for all different resolution of phones?

Comment: Then check the window/document size and set the chart's size